# Spring Custom AuthenticationProvider never invoked - 404 error on http://localhost:8080/igloo/j_spring_security_check

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to get an example of custom j_spring_security_check working on tomcat 7.0.47. Spring MVC goes to login page ok but gives error after clicking submit - what I am expecting is spring to fill in the user roles and then go to main.jsp.

spring main config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
    <!--  ############################################# -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="frostbyte.igloo" />
    <!--  ############################################# -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <!--  ############################################# -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!--  ############################################# -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <!--  ############################################# -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"></property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
    </bean>
    <!--  ############################################# -->
</beans>
```

spring security config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
    <!--  ############################################# -->
    <beans:bean id="FrostByteAuthenticationProvider" class="frostbyte.igloo.jsp.custom.FrostByteAuthenticationProvider"></beans:bean>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="FrostByteAuthenticationProvider"></authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <!--  ############################################# -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-processing-url="/login"
                       login-page="/login"
                       default-target-url="/main"
                       username-parameter="j_username"
                       password-parameter="j_password"
                       authentication-failure-url="/login?auth=fail"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logout_success"></logout>
    </http>
    <!--  ############################################# -->
</beans:beans>
```

the AuthenticationProvider (non of these log messages ever get printed) :

```
package frostbyte.igloo.jsp.custom;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;   

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

import frostbyte.common.FrostbyteRole;
import frostbyte.common.FrostbyteUser;

public class FrostByteAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider
{

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FrostByteAuthenticationProvider.class);

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication)
    {
        LOG.error("FrostByteAuthenticationProvider : supports : Marker 1");
        System.out.println("FrostByteAuthenticationProvider : supports : Marker 1");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        LOG.error("FrostByteAuthenticationProvider : authenticate : Marker 1");
        System.out.println("FrostByteAuthenticationProvider : authenticate : Marker 1");
        Authentication rtn = null;
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        LOG.error("FrostByteAuthenticationProvider : authenticate : Marker 10 : username = "+username);
        LOG.error("FrostByteAuthenticationProvider : authenticate : Marker 20 : password = "+password);
        FrostbyteUser user = new FrostbyteUser(); //for test everything validates
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.getRoles().add(new FrostbyteRole("ADMIN"));
        LOG.debug("Authenticate : Marker 100");
        //if (user.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase("username"))
        if (true)
        {
            LOG.debug("Authenticate : Marker 200");
            if (true)
            //if (password.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getPassword()))
            {
                LOG.debug("Authenticate : Marker 300");
                List<GrantedAuthority>  grants = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                for (FrostbyteRole _role:user.getRoles())
                {
                    if (_role.equals("ADMIN"))
                    {
                        for ( String __role : _role.getRoles() )
                        {
                            grants.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(__role.toUpperCase()));
                        }
                    }
                }
                rtn = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, grants);
                LOG.debug("Authenticate : Marker 898,000 : rtn = "+ rtn);
            }
            LOG.debug("Authenticate : Marker 899,000 : rtn = "+ rtn);
        }
        LOG.debug("Authenticate : Marker 900,000 : rtn = "+ rtn);
        return rtn;
    }

}
```

the login jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
      <style type="text/css"></style>
   </head>
   <body>
     request.getAttribute("message") = <%= request.getAttribute("message") %>
     <br />
     request.getParameter("message") = <%= request.getParameter("message") %>
     <form action="<c:url value = "/j_spring_security_check" />" method="post">     
         <br /><br /><br />
         <br /><br /><br />      
         <br />
         <div class="containerCenterAlign">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="titleClass">Igloo<br /><div class="errorMessage"><%= message %></div></div>
                  <ul class="loginUL">
                      <li class="loginLeft">
                           <label class="loginLabel" for="j_username">Username</label>
                           <input id="username" name="j_username" class="loginText" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" />
                           <label class="loginLabel" for="j_password">Password</label>
                           <input id="password" name="j_password" class="loginText" type="password" value="" maxlength="150" />
                       </li>
                       <li class="loginRight">
                           <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" class="loginSubmit" />                           
                       </li>
                   </ul>
                   <div style="clear: both; height: 2px;"></div>
              </div>
         </div>
     </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

include.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="frostbyte.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.log4j.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="sform" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="frostbyte" uri="http://frostbyte/tags" %>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to stumble across the fix by removing

login-processing-url="/login"

I am posting these results here since its almost impossible to find good spring tutorials, even in the 4 spring books I have. Note I also had to add filter for the resources